# Use of complex filters in Janrain's entity.find

Tags: janrain

I'm having trouble figuring out how to supply the filter parameter based on nested json objects within the entity schema. I can easily use the outer basic fields like filter="givenName='Taylor'" but to go deeper within the hierarchies of data, I can't find a way to do it.

In addition to that, I'm having trouble figuring out how to supply a filter parameter to just query the records that contain a specific provider such as facebook. The only way I'm seeing is by looking at each json object under "profiles", then "accessCredentials" then "domain".

Another example is when I was trying to use "gender='male'" as a filter. Since gender isn't at the outer level of the schema, this doesn't seem to work. It lives within the Facebook profile, then gender, so I assume the filter needs to be able to specific that key at a lower level or along a path of some sort.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doing a few levels deeper in the schema in searches, you can use dot or slash notation.

```
profiles.profile.quotes.quote = 'Love is a snowmobile racing across the tundra and then suddenly it flips over, pinning you underneath. At night, the ice weasels come. - Matt Groening'
```

or

```
profiles/profile/quotes/quote = 'wat'
```

As for gender, you might try

```
gender = 'male' OR profiles.profile.gender = 'male'
```

Comment: That worked great.  To pull just facebook users, I used filter=profiles.domain=facebook.com.  It was the "dot" notation to drill down to nested levels that I was missing and couldn't find any documentation on.  I couldn't get the slash notation to work. Thanks.